# Mongodb: Can't $push an object into an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to `$push` an object into an empty array in Mongodb in Node, and I can't do it. However, with the same code, `$push`ing just a number (for example) does work.

Any ideas?

My document:

```
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "5d390a119dc142572d0abef8"
  },
  "LastName": "Musk",
  "FirstName": "Elon",
  "myArr": []
}
```

Working:

```
let numb = 123;
docs.forEach((doc) => {
  db.collection(collection).update({ _id: doc._id }, { $push: { myArr: numb } });
})
```

Not working:

```
let obj = { string: "Hello world", number: 123 };
docs.forEach((doc) => {
  db.collection(collection).update({ _id: doc._id }, { $push: { myArr: obj } });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried on **GUI for MongoDB** it's working :

**Query** :

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').update({ _id: ObjectId("5b67f2a6bcc32c793f09c209")},{ $push: { myArr: { string: "Hello world", number: 123 } } });
```

**collection output after run above query**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b67f2a6bcc32c793f09c209"),
    "value1" : [ 
        "a", 
        "b"
    ],
    "myArr" : [ 
        {
            "string" : "Hello world",
            "number" : 123.0
        }
    ],
    "value2" : "ccc"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to follow up, it does seem to be saving the data for me, the data just isn't showing up on the mLab document for some reason. But it is there (I can retrieve it through a query, for example).